# Repeat action on button click in telebot module

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm implementing a simple function in Python, but it doesn't work

Function:

```
# Рандомное число с кнопкой
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'], commands=['get_number'])
def get_number(message):
    number = random.randint(0, 1000)
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Да', callback_data='yes')
    item_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Нет', callback_data='no')
    markup.row(item_yes, item_no)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"<i><b>Ваше число:</b></i>\n{number}\n\nЗагадать еще раз?", reply_markup=markup,
                 parse_mode='html')


# Реакция на нажатие кнопки
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer(call, message):
    if call.data == 'yes':
        pass
    elif call.data == 'no':
        pass
```

Tell me how to make it so that when you click the "Yes" button, the function is executed when you click it again, when you click "No", it stops accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can change your method:

```py
def answer(call, message):
```

for

```py
def handle_query(call):
```